# How to Retrieve most recent completed, todo events from default calendar in iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, ekevent, ekeventkit, ekeventstore

I am using default calendar in iOS5. I have to display most recent three completed activities, most recent three  todo events.Those events can be any thing,means it can be any day.

Can any one help me how retrieve those events using ekevnt store.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can make use of this `enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:usingBlock:` Write predicate to get all the events, then in block callback process for 3 events and then stop.

Comment: I accept with this.But how do i know start, end dates of events occurred.do i need to keep previous six months, next six months>